# How to copy and paste text from Windows notepad to Nano editor running in Ubuntu( running in VMWare Workstation Player )

Tags: windows-10, vmware, nano

Background:
Physical machine is Windows 10.
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is running on VMware Workstation Player, in the same Windows 10 machine.

When I try to copy a text from notepad to Ubuntu terminal or nano editor, nothing is happening.
I tried shift+ctrl+v. Did not help.

I found a link
[How to copy text from Host machine and paste it into nano editor in Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856114/how-to-copy-text-from-host-machine-and-paste-it-into-nano-editor-in-ubuntu-serve)
Which explains about installing an extension in VirtualBox to get the same task to be accomplished.

Any ideas about how to do this ?

Comment: I don't know anything about VMWare, but Google have me [this](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/57122). The problem appears to be related to Windows and VMware.

Comment: You should install VMware Tools: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/340

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  Thank you for giving a direction, any specific VMware tool i should go for ? Am not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

**to copy text from host to guest you need to follow this steps:**

1. ensure that your host ubuntu is updated by this two commands:

   sudo apt update

   sudo apt upgrade
2. open your vbox and start the virtual guest environment.
3. use the toolbar click on Devices then> click on Insert Guest Additions CD image.
4. after installing or upgrading the guest addition you need to ensure that the Virtual Box accepting "Shared Clipboard".
5. go to your virtual box> click on Settings then> General > Advanced and change the Shared Clipboard to "Bidirectional".
6. now reboot your Virtual Box and it should work.
7. Notice that in every environment ou use you should copy and paste in the environment shortcuts (cntrl+shift+c) for ubuntu (cntrl+c) for windows and so on.

**notice:** after upgrading your ubuntu os you might need to update your guest additions to.

hope that will help you out.

Comment: This explanation is for VirtualBox. For VMware you have to install VMware Tools: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/340